# Email body line by line

Tags: vb.net

I use email to send my emails out. In body clause i use this code below. In bodyText variable i insert text comming from stringbuilder. However at the end when my email is received all text are not line b line but in one line. What am i doing wrong?

```
Mail.Body = "<HTML><HEAD></head><BODY style='font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma'>" + "<P>" & "Hi there," & ",</p>" + "<p>" & bodyText & "</p>" & "<p>This e-mail is generated automatically therefore <b>do not reply to this email.</b></p>" + "<p>Developer, </p>" & "Development team" & "</BODY></HTML>"
```

Stringbuilder:

```
_strbuild.Append("Start" + Environment.NewLine).AppendLine()

_strbuild.Append("Start" + Environment.NewLine).AppendLine()
```

Comment: Your lacking in too many details for this to be answerable.  Random guess is you should be using mail.htmlbody.

Answer (score 0):

You create some HTML so you have to use the HTML new line (`<br>`):

```
_strbuild.Append("Start" + "<br>")
_strbuild.Append("Start" + "<br>")
```

Instead of using the system new line (`\r\n` or `\n`) you have to use the `<br>` element. In HTML you can use the system new line only to format the HTML code not to format the output.

Answer (score 0):

When the body of the message is sent in HTML format, add the 
 (break - br) tags right in your String. vbCrLf and StringBuilder are not suggested as they don't work if the body is in HTML format.

```
Dim mail As New MailMessage
mail.IsBodyHtml = True
mail.Body = "Line one<br>"
mail.Body += "Line Two<br>"
mail.Body += "More Lines"
```

Answer (score 0):

`Environment.NewLine` does not work because the current environment for your program is not the same environment where the user will read your result. Your environment is a console program (masquerading as a scheduled task or service), or web server application, or windows form, or something else where outputting a simple `\n` character results in a new line. The same applies to `AppendLine()`. It's using `Environment.NewLine` behind the scenes, and again, the problem is that your program environment is different than your user's environment.

In this case, your user's environment is an html document. *HTML treats all simple whitespace the same, as a single space*. This is true whether you have a tab, newline, space, or any multiples or combination of the above. It all consolidates to a single space in html.

So for html, in order to force a line break, you should instead include a `<br>` tag with your html. More than this, HTML will break up the lines automatically; you might get away without doing anything. Even in cases where you want an explicit line break what you're typically really doing from a semantic standpoint is asking for a new paragraph. This means `<p>` is commonly more appropriate:

```
_strbuild.Append("Start").Append("<p>")
```

If you really don't want the extra blank line from the new paragraph you can use styles to remove or reduce it (though admittedly e-mail is the one place where breaking the correct p vs br semantics *might* be appropriate: e-mail renderers can be difficult).